# python: splitting filenames to order sequentially

Tags: python, list, sorting, directory, filenames

I have filenames like this:

```
'./images/X_0_image0.png',
'./images/X_0_image1.png',
'./images/X_0_image10.png',
'./images/X_0_image100.png',
'./images/X_0_image101.png',
```

in a directory containing a lot. How do I read the content such that I obtain a list of paths and filenames sorted in ascending order like for a human count, i.e. not having X_0_image100.png appear after X_0_image10.png. I want to store those in a dataframe so that they match the orginal index order in which they were created row wise from 0 index to end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

```py
# Randomly ordered:
filenames = [
    './images/X_0_image10.png',
    './images/X_0_image0.png',
    './images/X_0_image1.png',
    './images/X_0_image101.png',
    './images/X_0_image100.png',
]

trim_length = len('./images/X_0_image')

sorted_filenames = [
    x[1] for x
    in
    sorted([
        (int(filename.split('.')[1][trim_length-1:]), filename)
        for filename
        in filenames
    ])
]

print(sorted_filenames)
```

Comment: It works like magic, can you please explain. I see you weed out the prefix part using len() (much better than regex here) but then I get lost with the rest. I can see you're using the index of the split remainder...

Comment: @Zen4ttitude No, that's your homework :D

Comment: You could also do `sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda s: int(s.removeprefix('./images/X_0_image').removesuffix('.png')))`; or alternatively: `trim_length = len('./images/X_0_image'); sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda s: int(s[trim_length:-4]))`

Comment: Also, the square brackets `[ ... ]` are unnecessary in `sorted([ blabla for filename in filenames ])`; you can write directly `sorted( blabla for filename in filenames )` without the brackets (and it's actually more efficient)

Comment: @Stef your approach is more intuitive but the use of len() the way m_ocean did wins me over for cleverness. I can understand yours better though so it's a draw for best answer!

Comment: @Zen4ttitude Note I suggested two alternatives in my comment. The second one uses `len` also. But may I suggest a third one? `trim_length = len('./images/X_0_image'); sorted_filenames = sorted(filenames, key=lambda s: int(s.split('.')[1][trim_length-1:])))`

Comment: It's almost exactly the same as in the answer, except it uses the `key` optional argument of `sorted`, in order to avoid `[x[1] for x in sorted((pair whose first element is the key and second element is filename) for filename in filenames)]`. See also paragraphs "Key functions" and "Decorate-Sort-Undecorate" of [Python Sorting How-To](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html)